# Heatmap of an image

Tags: raw, image-processing

I want to create the heatmap of an image for research purposes. 
Is there any algorithm to create heatmap of an image ?

Also, if I have a RAW image out of a Nikon D5200 (.NEF file format), will it have the temperature information saved within itself ?

Comment: What do you mean by a heatmap of an image? What do you imagine as your ultimate end-product?

Comment: Are you talking about eye-tracking heat maps? Or literal temperature of objects in the scene?

Comment: Since OP talks about temperature, me thinks we can assume heat as in warm and very warm.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about using a camera as a temperature measuring device, rather than to produce photographs with artistic or historical value.

Answer (score 5):

No. They only record visible light (+/- a few nm).

If you want heat images (Infra Red "light"), you might want to look at [the FLIR C2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00T9RANUC)

Comment: unless, of course, we are taking photos of very hot objects, where thermal radiation enters the visible range ;-) then we could try to infer the temperature from the blackbody radiation colors

Comment: @szulat Edge case ;) It does contain temperature information, but not directly only via the wavelength of the emitted light

Comment: Plus, a camera never gives the true spectrum, just a mixture of red, green and blue. For example, a sodium lamp gives a very pure yellow, but the photo taken does not contain any yellow, just red, green and blue. The brain maps this mixture to yellow again.

Comment: @sweber Well, kind of. The actual colors of the Bayer mask for most common cameras are a slightly violet blue that we call "Blue", a slightly bluish green that we call "Green", and somewhere between a greenish yellow to a yellowish orange that we call "Red". The colors of the Bayer mask filters do not correspond to the R, G, and B channels of tri-color display devices. The 'Red' channel, particularly, does not even come remotely close. Look at the peak of each color channel on sensitivity maps of camera sensors and you'll see that the 'Red' channel is usually centered at about 590nm, not 640.

Comment: @sweber For a fuller treatment of the subject, please see: [Why are Red, Green, and Blue the primary colors of light?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/99706/15871)

Comment: @michaelclark: absolutely true, but didn't fit here ;-)

Comment: The point is, many Bayer masks have 'Red' filters that are most sensitive to right around 589nm, which is the wavelength of the sodium D lines in spectrometers.